# Обьединение двусвязных линейных списков

Tags: c++

Вообщем есть программа, все в ней меня устраивает, но функция void connector не выполняет свою задачу в полной мере, то есть задание обьединить два списка в один, указав конец первого списка, на начало второго, а я же просто взял и вывел оба списка один за другим. Как мне реализовать правильное обьединение списков?

Код:

*Файл Main.cpp:*

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Header.h"

void additem(list* &p, int num) {
    list* q = new list;
    q->a = num;
    q->next = nullptr;
    q->prev = nullptr;
    if (p == nullptr) {
        p = q;
    }
    else {
        list* tmp = p;
        while (tmp->next) {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        q->prev = tmp;
        tmp->next = q;
    }
}

void additem2(list2* &p2, int num2) {
    list2* q2 = new list2;
    q2->a2 = num2;
    q2->next2 = nullptr;
    q2->prev2 = nullptr;
    if (p2 == nullptr) {
        p2 = q2;
    }
    else {
        list2* tmp2 = p2;
        while (tmp2->next2) {
            tmp2 = tmp2->next2;
        }
        q2->prev2 = tmp2;
        tmp2->next2 = q2;
    }
}

list* construct(int n) {
    list* p;
    p = nullptr;
    int a;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a;       /*Ввод следующих элементов*/
        additem(p, a);
    }
    return p;
}

list2* construct2(int n2) {
    list2* p2;
    p2 = nullptr;
    int a2;
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < n2; i2++) {
        cin >> a2;      /*Ввод следующих элементов*/
        additem2(p2, a2);
    }
    return p2;
}

void delfirst(list* &p) {
    list* del = p;
    p = p->next;
    p->prev = nullptr;
    delete del;
}

void dellast(list* &p) {
    list* tmp = p;
    while (tmp->next) tmp = tmp->next;
    list* del = tmp;
    tmp->prev->next = nullptr;
    delete del;
}

void delorder(list* &p, int n) {
    list* tmp = p;
    int i = 1;
    if (n == 1) delfirst(p);
    else {
        while (i < n && tmp) {
            tmp = tmp->next;
            i++;
        }

        if (!tmp->next) dellast(tmp);
        else {
            tmp->prev->next = tmp->next;
            tmp->next->prev = tmp->prev;
            delete tmp;
        }
    }
}

void insertbefore(list* &p, int num, int ins) {
    list* tmp = p;
    while (tmp->a != num) tmp = tmp->next;
    list* insert = new list;
    insert->a = ins;
    if (tmp->prev == nullptr) {
        additem(tmp, ins);
    }
    else {
        tmp->prev->next = insert;
        insert->prev = tmp->prev;
        tmp->prev = insert;
        insert->next = tmp;
    }
}

void filewritetxt(list* p) {
    ofstream file1;
    file1.open("1.txt", ios_base::app);
    while (p) {
        file1 << p->a << " ";
        p = p->next;
    }
    file1.close();
}

void filewritebin(list* p) {
    ofstream file2;
    file2.open("2.bin", ios::binary);
    while (p) {
        file2 << p->a << " ";
        p = p->next;
    }
    file2.close();
}

void fileread(list* p) {
    char buff[500];

    cout << "\nСчитывание с текстового файла:" << endl;
    ifstream file3("C:\\users\\laptopchik\\source\\repos\\OP 11\\1.txt");
    file3.open("1.txt");
    if (file3) {
        while (!file3.eof()) {
            file3 >> buff;
            cout << buff;
        }
        file3.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Ошибка открытия файла!" << endl;
    }

    char buff2[500];

    cout << "\n\nСчитывание с бинарного файла:" << endl;
    ifstream file4("C:\\users\\laptopchik\\source\\repos\\OP 11\\2.txt", ios::binary);
    file4.open("2.bin");
    if (file4) {
        while (!file4.eof()) {
            file4 >> buff2;
            cout << buff2;
        }
        file4.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Ошибка открытия файла!" << endl;
    }
    file4.close();

    cout << "\n";
}

void connector(list* p, list2* p2) {
    while (p && p2) {
        cout << p->a << "  ";
        p = p->next;
        cout << p2->a2 << "  ";
        p2 = p2->next2;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int amount;
    char menu;

    do {
        cout << "Укажите количество элементов списка:\n > ";
        cin >> amount;
    } while (amount <= 0);
    cout << "Введите элементы списка:\n";
    list *a = construct(amount);
    show(a);
    do {
        cout << "Выберите пункт меню:\n";
        cout << "1 - Прибавить элемент в конец списка\n";
        cout << "2 - Вставить элемент перед элементом с указанным значением\n";
        cout << "3 - Удалить первый элемент в списке\n";
        cout << "4 - Удалить элемент с указанным порядковым номером\n";
        cout << "5 - Удалить последний элемент в списке\n";
        cout << "6 - Записать список в текстовый и бинарный файлы\n";
        cout << "7 - Вывести список из бинарного и текстового файлов\n";
        cout << "8 - Создать второй список и обьединить его с первым\n";
        cout << "0 - Выход\n";

        cin >> menu;

        switch (menu) {
            case '1': {
                int num;
                cout << "Введите число, которое хотите добавить:";
                cin >> num;
                additem(a, num);
                show(a);
                cout << endl;
                break;
            }
            case '2': {
                int num;
                int numch;
                cout << "Введите число, перед которым хотите вставить:";
                cin >> numch;
                cout << "Введите число, которое хотите добавить:";
                cin >> num;
                insertbefore(a, numch, num);
                show(a);
                cout << endl;
                break;
            }
            case '3': {
                delfirst(a);
                show(a);
                cout << endl;
                break;
            }
            case '4': {
                int n;
                cout << "Какое по счету число вы хотите удалить? \n > ";
                cin >> n;
                delorder(a, n);
                show(a);
                cout << endl;
                break;
            }
            case '5': {
                dellast(a);
                show(a);
                cout << endl;
                break;
            }
            case '6': {
                filewritetxt(a);
                filewritebin(a);
                cout << "Список записан в текстовый и бинарный файлы!\n\n";
                break;
            }
            case '7': {
                fileread(a);
                break;
            }
            case '8': {
                int amount2;
                do {
                    cout << "Укажите количество элементов второго списка:\n > ";
                    cin >> amount2;
                } while (amount2 <= 0);
                cout << "Введите элементы списка:\n";
                list2 *a2 = construct2(amount2);
                show2(a2);
                cout << "Обьединенные списки:\n";
                connector(a, a2);
                cout << endl;
                break;
            }
            default: {
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (menu != '0');

    system("pause");
}
```

*Файл Header.h:*

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct list {
    int a;
    list* next;
    list* prev;
};

void show(list* p) {
    while (p) {
        cout << p->a << "  ";
        p = p->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

struct list2 {
    int a2;
    list2* next2;
    list2* prev2;
};

void show2(list2* p2) {
    while (p2) {
        cout << p2->a2 << "  ";
        p2 = p2->next2;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас совершенно не допустимая архитерура. Должно быть одно определение структуры list, а не list и list2. А экземплятор list может быть много. Иными словами стираем строки

```
struct list2 {
    int a2;
    list2* next2;
    list2* prev2;
};
```

`list2`, `a2`, `next2`, `prev2` везде меняем на `list`, `a`, `next`, `prev`. Было бы не плохо в list `a` переименовать в `data`, к примеру.
Заметьте, после этого копипаста станет не нужна, и функции `show2`, `construct2` и `additem2` станут не нужны. Они один в один совпадут с `show`, `construct` и `additem`

Объединение двух списков: есть простой вариант и сложный. Простой просто меняет ссылки и портит входящие списки:

```
list* join(list* begin, list* end) {
    if(begin == nullptr) {
        return end;
    }
    if(end == nullptr) {
        return begin;
    } 
    list* tmp = begin;
    while (tmp->next) {
            tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    tmp.next = end;
    end.prev = tmp;
    return begin;
}
```

Сложный - создать новый список и скопировать в него сначала все значения первого, потом второго списка.

```
list* join(list* begin, list* end) {
    list* joinList = nullptr;
    while (begin != nullptr) {
        additem(joinList, begin->data);
        begin = begin->next;
    }
    while (end != nullptr) {
        additem(joinList, end->data);
        end = end->next;
    }
    return joinList;
}
```

P.S. Писал с телефона, могут быть опечатки.

Comment: Спасибо! Если я Вас правильно понял, то функции show2, construct2, additem2 и структура list2 вовсе в коде не нужны?

Comment: @MrInno, да, не нужны.